# El resultado me lo devuelve vacio Laravel + Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Buenas a través de un ajax quiero generar consultas cada minuto a una query, no me da error pero no me devuelve nada.

```
   let res = "";

  (function($) {
   var fnConsulta = function(){
    $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    url : '{{ asset('admin/notificaciones/') }}', 
    type : 'GET', 
    success: function (response) {
          res = response;
          console.log(res);
          $( "#respuestaTotalMensajes" ).html(response);
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
    });
    };
  fnConsulta();
  timerConsulta = setInterval(function(){
  fnConsulta();
  }, 60000);
  })(jQuery);
```

**El route**

```
Route::get('admin/notificaciones', function (){
        $mesajillos = DB::table('mensajes')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                     ->where('status', 0)
                     ->get();

    });
```

Comment: No tiene caso enviar esto: `'X-CSRF-TOKEN` si tu petición es `GET`

Comment: Cierto, lo tenia cuando estaba probando por post @BetaM